# How to return NA when nothing is found in an xpath?

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing

It is difficult to formulate the question, but with an example, it is simple to understand.

I use R to parse html code.

In the following, I have a html code called `html`, then I try to extract all values in `//span[@class="number"]` and all values in `//span[@class="surface"]`:

```
html <- '<div class="line">
<span class="number">Number 1</span>
<span class="surface">Surface 1</span>
</div>
<div class="line">
<span class="surface">Surface 2</span>
</div>' 

page = htmlTreeParse(html,useInternal = TRUE,encoding="UTF-8")

number = unlist(xpathApply(page,'//span[@class="number"]',xmlValue))
surface = unlist(xpathApply(page,'//span[@class="surface"]',xmlValue))
```

The output for `number` is:

```
[1] "Number 1"
```

The output for `surface` is:

```
[1] "Surface 1" "Surface 2"
```

Then, when I try to `cbind` the two elements, I can't, because they don't have the same length.

So my question is: what can I do to have an output for `number` that is:

```
[1] "Number 1" NA
```

Then I can combine `number` and `surface`.

Comment: Are you trying to make sure that the number and surface pairs are kept together? Because this method will easily get confused say if you had a third line that only had a number. Then both lists will return two elements but they aren't necessarily paired together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to select the enclosing tag (the `div` here) for each, and look for each tag inside. With rvest and purrr, which I find simpler,

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

html %>% read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes('.line') %>% 
    map_df(~list(number = .x %>% html_node('.number') %>% html_text(), 
                 surface = .x %>% html_node('.surface') %>% html_text()))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>     number   surface
#>      <chr>     <chr>
#> 1 Number 1 Surface 1
#> 2     <NA> Surface 2
```

Comment: thank you alistaire, for the moment, I don't understand entirely your code, but it works. thank you. (`number=.x` means the xml value of number ?)

Comment: It uses CSS selectors instead of XPath, and `map_df` iterates across the results like `lapply`, but simplifies the results to a data.frame. Here I'm using its simplified anonymous function syntax, where `.x` is the value passed for that iteration.

Comment: OK, thank you. I am not familiar with CSS selector. And I simplified my code a little bit, if I have `<span class="number">Number<div>1</div></span>`, how can I get the value in `div`? with xPath, I can do `//span[@class="number"]/div`.

Comment: [Here's a really nice, quick tutorial on CSS selectors](http://flukeout.github.io/), but the equivalent would be `span.number div`. If you like XPath, though, `html_nodes` and `html_node` will take that, too, if you specify you're passing it to the `xpath` parameter.

Comment: you used a CCS selector, because, I have a value for class, right ? What if I don't have a class value. for exemple, in my previous comment, I have this code `<span class="number">Number<div>1</div></span>`, how can I get a matrix, for the value in the div (inside the span)? row 1 will be 1, and row 2 will be NA.

Comment: I assumed the class `line` was more specific than the tag `div`, but it would work fine with just `html_nodes('div')`. Or further specify which `div`s you're talking about with a more specific selector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137182/discussion-between-xr-sc-and-alistaire).

Answer (score 1):

```
library( 'XML' )  # load library
doc = htmlParse( html )  # parse html
# define xpath expression. div contains class = line, within which span has classes number and surface
xpexpr <- '//div[ @class = "line" ]'  

a1 <- lapply( getNodeSet( doc, xpexpr ), function( x ) { # loop through nodeset
      y <- xmlSApply( x, xmlValue, trim = TRUE )  # get xmlvalue
      names(y) <- xmlApply( x, xmlAttrs ) # get xmlattributes and assign it as names to y
      y   # return y
    } )
```

loop through `a1` and extract values of `number` and `surface` and set names accordingly. Then column bind number and surface values

```
nm <- c( 'number', 'surface' )
do.call( 'cbind', lapply( a1, function( x ) setNames( x[ nm ], nm ) ) )
#                [,1]        [,2]       
# number  "Number 1"  NA         
# surface "Surface 1" "Surface 2"
```

Data:

```
html <- '<div class="line">
<span class="number">Number 1</span>
<span class="surface">Surface 1</span>
</div>
<div class="line">
<span class="surface">Surface 2</span>
</div>'
```

Comment: Let me know if this works for you, else I will delete it

Comment: hi @Sathish, thank you for your answer, but I was probably not clear enough, I wanted to build a matrix. but it seems that I can get a matrix with your solution... please see alistaire's solution, thank you