# How to replace NA values when parsing a html page to make a dataframe?

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

When trying to parse a html page, we can get NA values. So when we try to build a data frame with data in a list, missing values make it impossible.

Is there any easy way to succeed. please see the following example:

```
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

pg <- getURL("https://agences.axa.fr/ile-de-france/paris/paris-19e-75019")
page = htmlTreeParse(pg,useInternal = TRUE,encoding="UTF-8")
unlist(xpathApply(page,'//b[@class="Name"]',xmlValue))
data.frame(noms = unlist(xpathApply(page,'//b[@class="Name"]',xmlValue)),
           rue = unlist(xpathApply(page,'//span[@class="street-address"]',xmlValue)))
```

Comment: Because you're using `html_node` instead of `html_nodes`. Also, RCurl is unnecessary here; you can pass the URL directly to `read_html`.

Comment: Thank you @alistaire, I modified my question since the initial one was kind of stupid. and for this question, I already asked a similar one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588717/how-to-return-na-when-nothing-is-found-in-an-xpath, and I didn't succeed to find a solution based on your answer to the other questions.

Comment: A better question. You should show loading XML, though, for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

Using rvest and purrr (the tidyverse package for lists/functional programming, which pairs very nicely with rvest),

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

# be nice, only scrape once
h <- 'https://agences.axa.fr/ile-de-france/paris/paris-19e-75019' %>% read_html()

df <- h %>% 
  # select each list item
  html_nodes('div.ListConseiller li') %>% 
  # for each item, make a list of parsed name and street; coerce results to data.frame
  map_df(~list(nom = .x %>% html_node('b.Name') %>% html_text(), 
               rue = .x %>% html_node('span.street-address') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)))

df
#> # A tibble: 14 × 2
#>                          nom                     rue
#>                        <chr>                   <chr>
#> 1          Marie France Tmim                    <NA>
#> 2               Rachel Tobie                    <NA>
#> 3              Bernard Licha                    <NA>
#> 4               David Giuili                    <NA>
#> 5        Myriam Yajid Khalfi                    <NA>
#> 6              Eytan Elmaleh                    <NA>
#> 7           Allister Charles                    <NA>
#> 8             Serge Savergne   321 Rue De Belleville
#> 9           Patrick Allouche            1 Rue Clavel
#> 10              Anne Fleiter   14 Avenue De Laumiere
#> 11             Eric Fitoussi                    <NA>
#> 12 Jean-Baptiste Crocombette 1 Bis Rue Emile Desvaux
#> 13               Eric Zunino    14 Rue De Thionville
#> 14               Eric Hayoun                    <NA>
```

The code uses CSS selectors for brevity, but use XPath ones via the `xpath` parameter of `html_nodes` and `html_node`, if you prefer.

Comment: thank you @alistaire, now I begin to understand, and by the way, we can also use xpath : `xpath='//div[@class="ListConseiller"]//li'`:)

Comment: Probably I can just delete this question, it is the same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588717/how-to-return-na-when-nothing-is-found-in-an-xpath

Comment: could you please tell me why this doesn't work? `df <- h %>% 
  html_nodes('div.ListConseiller li') %>% 
  map_df(~list(nom = .x %>% html_nodes(xpath='//b[@class="Name"]') %>% html_text(), 
               rue = .x %>% html_nodes(xpath='//span[@class="street-address"]') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)))` or how can I find an equivalent way with `xpath`?

Comment: If you start XPath with `/`, it takes it as an absolute path, so starting with `//` always searches the whole DOM. Start without `/` and search the current node instead: `h %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class = "ListConseiller"]/descendant::li') %>% map_df(~list(nom = .x %>% html_node(xpath='.//b[@class="Name"]') %>% html_text(), rue = .x %>% html_node(xpath='.//span[@class="street-address"]') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)))`